# Locked documents in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, office-integration

I have the following issue with some office documents I'm creating programmatically. Here are some insights:

1. The document is in Office >= 2010
2. I'm reading an office word document which is located in another document library, then I parse it with the open xml document api in order to remove al its embedded metadata, then I save the new document in the target library.
3. Target libraries have their check in / out (versioning) disabled (the library is created declaratively, checked the versioning settings just to make sure)
4. The document is opened by one user at all times.

So the basic creation process is as follows:

- The user picks up a "template" (which is the original word document)
- The user writes a document name for the new document and presses the "generate button"
- Then a javascript function calls a scriptable web service which does all the "magic" described previously
- The web service returns to the browser the document path (url)
- The browser calls `editDocumentWithProgID2(result, '', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', '0', '', '0');` to open the new document so the user can begin editing

Unfortunately, when the user tries to save the document office pop ups the following error message (before you say its an OS X bug, no, it happens in the latest office builds for windows too):

[image]

Any ideas what might be happening?

EDIT: adding code for more insight

Here's the code sample https://gist.github.com/jjaramillo/5605d069de25753005f7

Comment: Can you show some insight about code using which you are generating document? because it may be possible that you have not disposed/closed memorystream/binary after saving document?

Comment: Edited the question with the link to the sample code on github